# When to assign db_owner role to database users

Tags: sql-server, database-design

This is a long question, but please bear with me as I believe it raises important issues about database ownership and access.

I manage and internationally market a "universal" geothermal data management program, written in Delphi, that is a front end to a SQL Server database.  The data in the database is derived from many diverse measurements generated and used by the program users over time periods of 30 years or more - i.e. they "own" the data, and the database is primarily a way to efficiently store and manage the data.

Like all databases, the database structure needs to be modified from time to time, including new tables, and this modification is delivered by the release of a new version of the program.  The program prompts for a database upgrade, which has to be carried out by a dbo user so that all new tables can be accessed by the other program users.  Unfortunately, the program may be used in remote sites and the IT personnel may not be readily available, so that the new version may get installed but the databases are not upgraded.  What has frequently happened in such locations is that a program user will upgrade the databases without appropriate SQL Server permissions, and then the other users cannot access the new tables and the program crashes.

One of the program customers has taken another approach.  They have created a db_owner role for all the databases used by the program and then make all program users members of the db_owner role.  The program has inbuilt permission levels that can restrict the ability to upgrade databases, so normally only one or two users have this permission.  However, with everyone a member of the db_owner role, it doesn't matter who upgrades the database, all tables will be accessible to all program users.

The advantage of this approach include the following:

1. Access permissions can be granted by the group who uses the program, and who has ultimate responsibility for the database.
2. Knowledge and understanding of the program is passed on within the program users group when staff changes, rather than relying on the IT department as the repository of information on "how it works" (and often they do not know).
3. Direct data-mining and back-door data modification is possible to selected user experts.  While the program has extensive datasearch and editing tools, sometimes these are not enough and the users need hands-on access.
4. The program users retain "ownership" of their data.

I would appreciate your comments.  I believe that in circumstances such as these, it is important that all the database users are db_owners, and the group of users controls access. Not allowing db_owner roles (a strategy commonly employed by IT departments) fails to recognize the importance of data ownership and data accessibility, and the responsibility of the database users to manage their own data.

Answer (score 0):

The way you've stated your question makes it sound like you've already arrived at a conclusion. The one question that I always ask when someone comes to me (a DBA) with this sort of situation is: if someone accidentally deletes data, am I on the hook to get it back? If the answer is "yes", then they don't get db_owner. If the answer is "no", then the db gets moved to its own server and I get the contract in writing.

Answer (score 0):

The only time I wouldn't bother with access control would be with a simple app running on a local single-user database like `SqlExpress`. As soon as there are multiple users on a centralised database and important data to protect, restricted access is important. I'm not familiar with your domain (geothermal data management), but surely this data is important to your customers, from integrity, tampering and even a data access point of view (theft of data could be resold to a competitor).

> the program may be used in remote sites and the IT personnel may not
>   be readily available, so that the new version may get installed but
>   the databases are not upgraded

(i.e. I'm assuming an upgrade script needs to be manually and independently run on the database). It is common nowadays for apps to check the database for schema versioning and even for static data population, e.g. [Entity Framework code-first migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621) on the .net stack. The app will then have the ability to actually perform the schema and data upgrade automatically. It should be quite straightforward for you to add the last N versions of your DB upgrade scripts into your app and then do a version check? (Obviously the app itself would need to prompt for `dbo` access, assuming that even the app should not have dbo access).

> with everyone a member of the db_owner role, it doesn't matter who
>   upgrades the database

I believe this may place unnecessary responsibility (and power) in the hands of unqualified customer users.

Even the ad-hoc data mining (`SELECT`) access should be reconsidered, as a badly formed query without consideration can cause performance degradation or block other concurrent writers. If nothing else, providing a few well formed views will at least ensure decent query plans.

/10c